# clear:both with h2 tag: h2 margins doens't work

Tags: html, css

I have `float: left` div and I want to clear floats after it.
If I insert `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` just after floating div, then it works fine. The problem is that I need a solution without extra `div`.

I added `clear:both` for `h2` tag, it works, but h2 top margin are not taken into account.

HTML:

```
<p class="with_arrow_down">IF you don’t know the cost you are&nbsp;probably making the wrong decisions</p>
<!--<div style="clear:both;"></div>-->

<h2 class="bigmargin">Check list for maintaining the highest levels </h2>
```

CSS:

```
.with_arrow_down {        
    padding-top: 44px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 28%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    float: left;
}
.with_arrow_down:nth-of-type + * {
    clear: both;
}
h2.bigmargin {
    margin: 65px 0 65px 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

Please, explain me how to make h2 margins to work.

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smdgg/3/

Comment: Your fiddle omits the `clear:both`...adding this to the `h2.bigmargin` rules behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work.

Your JS Fiddle demo is missing the `clear: both` rule for the h2 that you have in the question.

If we [update it](http://jsfiddle.net/smdgg/1/) then the only problem is that it overlaps the previous content because that element has a fixed height so the content overflows, that can be demonstrated by [setting overflow hidden](http://jsfiddle.net/smdgg/2/).

Comment: I have updated my question. It really works, but margins doesn't work. See updated question. I copied those css and html from my website where it seemd that clear:both doesn't work, but actually margins doens't work.

Comment: @renathy — This answer already explains why the margins aren't working as you expect. Set overflow hidden on the arrow_down, or don't give it a fixed height.

Comment: I do not see how overflow hidden or not setting height will help. It still doesn't take margins into account. I need margin between h2 and .with_arrow_down

Comment: There is a margin between h2 and .with_arrow_down, it is just that because the height of with_arrow_down is fixed, the content of that element extends into and beyond that margin.